# HTML DIV COLUMN

Tags: html, multiple-columns

I want to ask why my html code with  and float can't divide the page into column form. I have already used float.I have seen other people code the similar things for dividing page to column.But Why it is not successful in this way.Is there any bug.

this is my html file.

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <title >
           Test
        </title>
    </head>


     <body>
     <h1 id="center" ><I>
     Testing
     </I></h1>   

    <div id="left_list">
       <ul  Type=Circle>
           <LI>Main Page</LI>
           <LI>Course</LI>
           <LI>Location</LI>
         </ul>

     </div>
     <div id="image">
      <img src="hi.png" alt="FAIL"> 
     </div>
    <div id="image">
      <img src="bye.png" alt="FAIL"> 
    </div>
    <div id="image">
      <img src="download.jfif" alt="FAIL"> 
    </div>


     <LINK REL=Stylesheet TYPE="text/css" HREF="style.css">
     </body>
     </html>
```

This is style.css

```
    #left_list{
    Font-size:20px;
    float: left;
    width:300px;
    margin-right:20px;
    height:800px;
    background-color:#00FF7F;
    clear:both;
    }



    #image{
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    height:800px;
    width:400px;
    clear:both;


    }

    #rightimage{
    float: right;
    margin-right:20px;
    height:800px;
    width:400px;
    clear:both;

    }

    #center{
    align:center;
    }



    body{
    background-color:#6495ED;
    }

    head{
    font-size:large;
    }
```

Comment: Your HTML is all kind of invalid. What's `</U1>`? Where are your `,body` tags? You can't put HTML in the `<head>` either. Start by validating your HTML.

Comment: but even if iIcorrect them . I find that it's still not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="clearfix" id="wrapper">
  <div id="left_list">
    <ul Type=Circle>
      <li>Main Page</li>
      <li>Course</li>
      <li>Location</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="image">
    <img src="hi.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

css code:

```
   #wrapper {
   margin-right: 200px;
   border:2px dashed red;
 }

 #image {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px;
   height: 400px;
   width: 200px;
   background: #444;
 }

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

you don't use clear:both for floating elements.

Comment: I have used clear:both  for floating element .But it also doesn't work

Comment: I posted my code in my question. I am the beginner of HTML. So hope you will pardon me for any silly mistake.